# refresh div automatically for news ticker

Tags: php, javascript, automation

is there anyway to refresh the contents of this div when the value from the feed.php changes

this is my code for the news ticker:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function bangingTicker(container,element) { 

    var tickContainer = $(container);  
        function tick(){ 
            var tickElem = tickContainer.children(element); 
            tickElem.eq(1).siblings().animate({ 
                opacity: 0 
                },400, function() { 
                    tickContainer.stop(true,true).delay(10).animate({ 
                    'margin-right': 10 
                    },0,function() { 
                        tickContainer.delay(100).animate({ 
                        'margin-right': 20 
                        },8000); 
                    }); 
                        tickElem.first().appendTo(tickContainer); 
                        tickElem.eq(1).delay(200).animate({ 
                            opacity: 1 
                        },400); 
                    }); 

        } 

        setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 6000); 

} 

bangingTicker('#testi_ticker','li');


$(document).ready(function(){
    bangingTicker('#testi_ticker','li');    
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('#testi_ticker').fadeIn(1000); 
    },6400); 
});


</script>
```

html script

```
    <div id="anc">
<label style="float:left;color:red;font-size:15px;margin-left:30px;margin-top:20px;"><b>ANNOUNCEMENT : </b>&nbsp;</label>
<ul id="testi_ticker" style="display:none;float:left;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;list-style:none;margin-top:20px;position:absolute;margin-left:180px;">
<?php echo $_SESSION['anc']; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

feed.php

```
<?php
session_start(); 

$mes1 = "test1";
$mes2 = "test2";
$mes3 = "test3";


$body = " <li>{$mes1} </li>
          <li>{$mes2} </li>
           <li>{$mes3} </li>
";

$_SESSION['anc'] = $body;

?>
```

is there anyway to update the output value on the html page , so that when i edit the "feed.php" the value on the html page will also be updated automatically?

Comment: use javascript to check if there is any thing new on your server (via ajax) and if so you update it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use JavaScript/Ajax. You can simply check call an Ajax-Request every few seconds or you use a technique called "Long Polling", here's a great video-tutorial for that:

http://www.screenr.com/SNH